# Why mapbox directions didn't support JSONP ? How to solve it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox, jsonp

I'm only using js without php, and i'm trying to get driving direction by calling api : https://api.mapbox.com/v4/directions/mapbox.driving/-122.42,37.78;-77.03,38.91.json?callback=jsonloaded&access_token=pk.mytoken

but the response didn't match the jsonp format like jsonloaded({someresponse})

I don't know if the developer make it intentionally or they forgot to make this service support jsonp. Maybe anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is a correct JSONP response: the only contract of JSONP is that it returns executable JavaScript that evaluates a function. Our prefix ensures that this endpoint cannot be used as an attack vector.

Are you having trouble using this endpoint with a JSONP library? It should be compatible with all JSONP implementations.

Comment: I'm using only jquery without any jsonp library, but it still getting CORS problem. There is no problem in mapbox v3, but in v4 it really stressfull. As far as I know, the response didn't match [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)